# Incorrect results for Integrate[Cosh[x]/(Sinh[x] + Cosh[x]), x]

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, symbolic

Input:

```mathematica
Clear[a, b];
a = FullSimplify[Integrate[Cosh[x]/(Sinh[x] + Cosh[x]), x]];
b = FullSimplify[Integrate[(E^x + E^-x)/(2 E^x), x]];
FullSimplify[Cosh[x]/(Sinh[x] + Cosh[x]) - ((E^x + E^-x)/(2 E^x))]
FullSimplify[a - b](* should return zero *)
```

Output:

0

-1/4

Using $\cosh x = \frac{e^{x} + e^{-x}}{2}$, $\cosh x + \sinh x = e^{x}$, and the fact that $e^{x}>0$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

$\int\frac{\cosh x}{\sinh x + \cosh x}dx = \int\frac{\frac{e^{x} + e^{-x}}{2}}{\sinh x + \cosh x}dx = \int\frac{e^{x} + e^{-x}}{2e^{x}}dx = \int\frac{1 + e^{-2x}}{2}dx = \frac{2x - e^{-2x}}{4} + C$

Answer (score 2):

result is correct. Anti derivative is correct up to arbitrary additive constant.

```
Clear[a, b];
integrandA = Cosh[x]/(Sinh[x] + Cosh[x])
antiA = FullSimplify[Integrate[integrandA, x]]
antiA = TrigToExp[antiA]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now

```
D[-(1/4)-E^(-2 x)/4+x/2,x]==integrandA//FullSimplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And also

```
D[-(E^(-2 x)/4)+x/2,x]==integrandA//FullSimplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

SO both are valid antiderivatives.

You have an extra constant in the anti-derivative which is `-1/4` which is causing the difference you see. You can always set that to zero if you want. It will not affect the final result.